# Why do I have requests to "/usr/share/nginx/www404"?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I have requests to

```
/usr/share/nginx/www404
```

in my NGINX logs. Note that www and 404 are mashed together.
The according line in my nginx.conf is

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

and there's a 404.html in my web root folder, sure. Clean config files here (btw why is it so hard to put code into a question here?):

- `nginx.conf` here: https://gist.github.com/panique/9003376
- `wordpress` (in sites-available) here: https://gist.github.com/panique/9003446

**My question:** Why are there requests to this weird "location" and what's wrong with my 404 error config ?

Comment: Could you insert the entire nginx conf ?
In what block error_page statement is included ?

Comment: Thanks, i've added ``nginx.conf` and the according `wordpress` setup from sites-available (as a gist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are :

In your PHP block you have this statement :

```
try_files $uri = 404;
```

Add this line in your PHP block:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

and change your error_page statement to :

```
error_page 404 = /404.html;
```